# Show a <li> line like is hovered

Tags: css, hover, html-lists, line

I have a simple CSS list. I want the first `<li>` line to be shown like is hovered. How can I do this? I had tried something like this: `<li class="#menu a:hover"><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>` but unfortunately doesn't work.

**Thank you for your time!**

The code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>A simple menu</title>
<style type="text/css">
#menu a:hover{
    background-color:   yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
 <body>
  <div id="menu">
   <ul>
    <li class="#menu a:hover"><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
   <ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want the yellow background for first link so do it like this

```
#menu ul li:nth-child(1) a {
    background-color:   yellow;
}
```

Or simply give a class for example `.current`

```
.current {
   background-color:   yellow;
}

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="current">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

If you are having any intentions to highlight the current page than answer is **NO**, you cannot do it with CSS, you will need JavaScript/jQuery or server side programming like PHP

Comment: Worth mentioning the OP has no need for those classes on the first LI that he has. I'm not even sure having a hash tag before text is a valid class name?

Comment: In addition to the second one you could use "#menu a:hover, #menu .current" so you have both in one.

Comment: @BillyMoat He is not using hash for naming purpose, he is trying to target that id, and so he is also using hash in the id, for example, if I am declaring a class called `.current` so he will use it like `<span class=".current">` instead of `<span class="current">`

Comment: @Mr.Alien - Ah, okay - I was confuddled!

Comment: I can't use `li:nth-child(1)` because is a CSS code. With CSS I know how I could do this. I'm trying to get the HTML code because I want to include this method in PHP with isset.

Comment: @CBuzatu ya than simply declare a class, and echo it out when the page is selected

Comment: Ok, I will assign `selected` class to a span: `<li><span class="selected"><a href="#">Option 2</a></span></li>` How can I write the `selected` class and the #menu div a:hover in one CSS rule? I tried something like this but doesn't work `#menu a:hover .selected {background-color:yellow;}`

Comment: @CBuzatu nah, define a class called `.current` now use that class like `<a href="#" class="current">Home</a>`

Comment: OK, is more easy. Thank you for help